# mysql, create field based on existing data

Tags: mysql

I want to add a field if possible that contains data from another field on the same table. In this case I want everythhing in table.newfield to show values from table.oldfield that are less than 100. Can I do this in sql? Or shall I stick to doing this in a select query for reports?

Mysql 5,1 innodb strict mode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could perform an update once you've added the new column eg

```
ALTER the table to add a Nullable Int/Long/??? called NewField

UPDATE Table SET NewField = OldField WHERE OldField<100
```

this woul, of course, only update when the query is run

You may also want to look into using views - these are effectively queries that are treated as tables. so you could have a view which does:

```
SELECT <Other Fields>,
    CASE WHEN OldField<100 THEN OldField
    ELSE NUll
END CASE
FROM table
```

(The syntax for the above is unchecked but should be approximately correct)

For more reading: [Creating Views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html), [MySQL Case Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html)

Comment: Thank you both are great answers. Wasn't sure how to apply a view, thanks for your great example, up and running :D

Answer (score 0):

if all you want is to display the short string, then do it all in SQL - do not store that data redundantly.

if you must store it again, then Basiclife got it right..